# Running GUI applications (DISPLAY) on jupyter notebook terminal - Linux

Tags: linux, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, display

We are running jupyter notebook on a Ubuntu server, and using terminal feature of jupyter. This is good for running CLI but when we have to run a GUI based application (e.g. xclock) then it says Can't Open Display.

If we run same GUI command by taking pytty session, from windows jumpserver, and setting DISPLAY variable, then it works fine (i.e., GUI application is displayed properly)

```
(base) sandeep:/data$ xclock
Error: Can't open display:
```

Ideally it should run if we set correct DISPLAY environment variable. However, what should be correct value of DISPLAY in case of jupyter notebook terminal, can anyone suggest please.

Answer (score 1):

Scenario: On your local computer, you want to open and manipulate an Juniper notebook running on a remote computer. We will do this by opening an SSH tunnel. This tunnel will forward the port used by the remotely running Jupyter instance to a port on the local machine, where it can be accessed in a browser just like a locally running Jupyter instance.

On the remote machine, start the Jupyter notebooks server:

```
remote_user@remote_host$ Jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889
```

Usually Jupyter opens a browser to display the available notebooks, but we do not need that so we use the option `--no-browser`. We also change the port to `8889`, for no other reason than to show how this is done.

On the local machine, start an SSH tunnel:

```
local_user@local_host$ ssh -N -f -L localhost:8888:localhost:8889 remote_user@remote_host
```

The first option `-N` tells SSH that no remote commands will be executed, and is useful for port forwarding. The second option `-f` has the effect that SSH will go to background, so the local tunnel-enabling terminal remains usable. The last option `-L` lists the port forwarding configuration (remote port 8889 to local port 8888).

Now open your browser on the local machine and type in the address bar

`localhost:8888`

which displays your remotely running Jupyter notebook server.

To close the SSH tunnel on the local machine, look for the process and kill it manually:

```
local_user@local_host$ ps aux | grep localhost:8889
local_user 18418  0.0  0.0  41488   684 ?        Ss   17:27   0:00 ssh -N -f -L localhost:8888:localhost:8889 remote_user@remote_host
local_user 18424  0.0  0.0  11572   932 pts/6    S+   17:27   0:00 grep localhost:8889
local_user@local_host$ kill -15 18418
```

Alternatively, you can start the tunnel without the `-f` option. The process will then remain in the foreground and can be killed with `ctrl-c`.

On the remote machine, kill the Jupyter server with `ctrl-c` `ctrl-c`.